# Remove y-axis tick labels on subplot with sharey=<other_axis>

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a multi-plot figure with subplots on python 3.7 and matplotlib. I have the plot set up where the first subplot (ax1) has `ax1.set_ylim()` and `ax2=plt.subplot(122, sharey=ax1)`

However, I would like to turn off the y-tick labels on ax2. When I do so via `ax2.set_yticks([])`, the tickmarks on both subplots go away (probably because of the `sharey`). See example below

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create data 
data1 = np.random.rand(10, 10)
data2 = np.random.rand(10, 10)

# plot data
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax1.imshow(data1)
ax1.set_ylim(0,5)

ax2 = plt.subplot(122, sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
ax2.imshow(data2)
ax2.set_yticks([])

plt.show()
```

Without setting `ax2.set_yticks([])`, I get the following:
[image: with-yticks]
But when I set `ax2.set_yticks([])`, both axes go away:
[image: without-yticks]

Is there a better way to do this? I'd like to have the y-axis labels on the left plot but not on the right.

Comment: You may want to just turn the labels off, instead of overwriting them with an empty list: `ax2.tick_params(labelleft=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this also:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create data 
data1 = np.random.rand(10, 10)
data2 = np.random.rand(10, 10)

# plot data
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4), sharey=True)
ax1.imshow(data1)
ax1.set_ylim(0,5)

ax2.imshow(data2)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is a good first step, but what exactly is going on with the x-axis on those figures? it seems like the left and right sides of it are being cut off

Comment: Your code creates the correct image when I run it, though I'm not sure why the image you linked is different. I'll mark the answer as complete, since the code solved my problem in exactly the right way.